# MPI Communicators management

Tags: c++, mpi

The question is if this procedure is correct?

**Lets say I want to split all `p` processes in `MPI_COMM_WORLD` into several non-overlapping communicators.
I do this by determining the `m` groups on one rank `master`. The master rank determines which processes need communication and which don't (analyzing a graph basically).**

At the end the `master` rank has determined these `m` groups of process ranks with which I want to build `m` communicators. 
Lets say I send these results of these `m` rank groups to all processes.

As I've found out is that all processes in MPI_COMM_WORLD need to make all these groups with the `MPI_Group_?` commands (even if they dont belong to the group, (stupidly ?)) and afterwards create each communicator with `MPI_Comm_create` **collectively**.

**The question now is**: What does a process do with all the communicators to which it **does not belong** and which are not needed by this process, but they were needed to call `m`-times the collective `MPI_Comm_create` function?

Can we simply neglect all the `MPI_Comm` pointers and only store the one to which this process belongs?, no need to call `MPI_Comm_free`?
How should I free the communicators if I want to rebuild another set of communicators?
Should a process only free its communicator to which it belongs?

Could somebody explain if this procedure is correct or not?
I am a bit unsure about this collective creation routines...

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you might be doing things the hard way.

The best way to split a large communicator into many non-overlapping subcommunicators is to use [`MPI_COMM_SPLIT`](http://www.mcs.anl.gov/research/projects/mpi/www/www3/MPI_Comm_split.html). The prototype looks like this:

```
int MPI_Comm_split(MPI_Comm comm, int color, int key, MPI_Comm *newcomm)
```

Everyone that will be in the same subcommuniator contributes the same `color`. Then the `key` is used to arrange the ranks within the subcommunicator. You can use the original rank if you want to maintain ordering.

The only thing you'll need to do before you call `MPI_COMM_SPLIT` is to broadcast the group numbers from the `master` process to everyone else using `MPI_BCAST`.

Comment: good answer, but it does not really help for my question. I know that I can split with this function and I also use this if I can in this case I cant and I was thinking about the above mentioned questions where I am very unsure about creating and freeing up communicators

Comment: I guess I don't understand why you need to create a bunch if extra communicators.

Comment: Isn't it that MPI_Comm_create is collective and all process need to call this function to make a new communicator even if it dont belongs to the new communicator and that is where it gets strange!

Comment: That's true. If you are using a new enough implementation of MPI, there is a new function that you can use called `MPI_COMM_CREATE_GROUP` that doesn't require anyone to participate.